# Reference third-party DLL in Visual Studio 2010 gives original DLL path?

Tags: visual-studio, dll, expression-blend-4

I'd like to add a third-party DLL from [Expression Blend](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Expression_Blend) 4 to my source control, so that I don't have to install Expression Blend (or perhaps just the SDK) on my [TFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Team_Foundation_Server) Build server, in order to have a succesful build.

I've copied the DLL file (`Microsoft.Expression.Interactions.dll`) from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Expression\Blend\.NETFramework\v4.0\Libraries` to the root of my source and checked the file into TFS.

However, if I reference the copied DLL fill (placed in `C:\Source\<Project>\Microsoft.ExpressionInteractions.dll`) via the Add Reference menu in Visual Studio 2010 the DLL file gets reference allright, but if I look at the properties windows for the reference, the path points to the original DLL file path (that is, `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Expression\Blend\.NETFramework\v4.0\Libraries\Microsoft.ExpressionInteractions.dll`).

If I remove the DLL file from the Blend-directory it works fine, but that's not a good solution, as I have other third party DLL files that I'd like to have added as well, as I'll loose control pretty quickly then and break a bunch of programs for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using the July 2010 version of the Productivity Power Tools for Visual Studio 2010 and using the Browse button to locate my DLL file within my source tree.

Apparently, the "Add Reference" functionality in the Power Tools somehow tries to "be smart" about referencing DLL files and changed the path for me.

After trying to add the DLL files on my laptop (where I don't have the Power Tools installed) the path is fine!?

I think I'll have to investigate this a bit more... But for now, this seems to be "the answer".